# Android Tabbed Activity with RecyclerView and Checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox, fragment, android-tabbed-activity

I have a tabbed activity which allows the user to select checkboxes for an entry in a recyclerview. When the user swipes between the different tabs the checkboxes do not retain their state of checked if they have been checked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
public class MyDirectory extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_directory);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);





        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "New Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Go", new View.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view)
                            {
                                Intent message = new Intent(MyDirectory.this, newScheduledNotification.class);
                                startActivity(message);
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_directory, menu);

        //SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(R.id.action_search);
        //searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(MyDirectory.this);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        else if (id == R.id.go_home)
        {
            Intent goHome = new Intent(MyDirectory.this, menuHomepage.class);
            startActivity(goHome);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {

        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber)
        {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        TextView textView;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        public List<directoryEntry> directoryEntryList = new ArrayList<>();
        directoryEntryAdapter dAdapter;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On Create View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String type = "";
            Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
            // Get Bundle Extras
            if (extras != null) {
                type = extras.getString("directoryAction");
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), type, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_directory, container, false);
            textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.directory_recycler_view);
            dAdapter = new directoryEntryAdapter(directoryEntryList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(dAdapter);


            if (type.equals("Send Instruction"))
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IN IF STATEMENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TextView instructionText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.InstructionField);
                instructionText.setText("Choose All Recipients");
            }



            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1)
            {
                prepareParentData(rootView);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format) + " Parent Directory");
                return rootView;
            }

            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2)
            {
                prepareTeacherData(rootView);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format) + " Staff Directory");
                return rootView;
            }

            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3)
            {
                prepareStudentData(rootView);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format) + " Student Directory");
                return rootView;
            }

            else
                return rootView;



        }


        public void prepareParentData(View rootview)
        {
            String method = "parent_directory";
            if(getActivity() == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (getActivity() != null)
            {
                DirectoryBackgroundTask directoryBackgroundTask = new DirectoryBackgroundTask(getActivity(), rootview);
                directoryBackgroundTask.execute(method);
            }
        }

        public void prepareTeacherData(View rootView)
        {
            String method = "faculty_directory";
            DirectoryBackgroundTask directoryBackgroundTask = new DirectoryBackgroundTask(getActivity(), rootView);
            directoryBackgroundTask.execute(method);
        }

        public void prepareStudentData(View rootView)
        {
            String method = "student_directory";
            DirectoryBackgroundTask directoryBackgroundTask = new DirectoryBackgroundTask(getActivity(), rootView);
            directoryBackgroundTask.execute(method);
        }
    }



    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Parent Directory";
                case 1:
                    return "Staff Directory";
                case 2:
                    return "Student Directory";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```